# Wireless key locking/unlocking diagnosis

Tags: toyota, fob, central-locking

I have a 2019 Toyota Land Cruiser. While locking all the doors with the FOB it locks fine. But, while unlocking it shows a delay of close to 2 seconds. I have replaced the FOB battery and the FOB. Still there is this delay. While using the master switch to lock and unlock all doors it works good and locks and unlocks on time. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Your car should be in warranty, go talk with the dealer. This might be like this on all models or might be some other problem we can only guess it here.